# How to find and replace all *=* with * = *

Tags: regex, xcode

I have a large xcode project with many classes. Few classes contain `=` without any space like this

`var name="john"`

In most places I have the code with proper space like this

`var id = 10`

What I want is

- Find `*=*` and replace with `* = *`
- Find `*==*` and replace with `* == *`
- Find `*!=*` and replace with `* != *`
- Find `*>=*` and replace with `* >= *`
- Find `*<=*` and replace with `* <= *`

It could be anything like `var a=b`, `view.isHidden=false`, `if(a==b)`, `dict["a"]=b`, etc.

I tried <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> Find -> Regular Expression -> `.*?=`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your updated question where you want to find and replace the operators `=`, `==`, `!=`, `<`, `<=`, `>`, and `>=` without spaces on both sides, and add the spaces you can use the following regular expressions:

For the search field:

```
([\w\]])(=|==|<|<=|>|>=|!=)([\w"])
```

for the replace field:

```
$1 $2 $3
```

This will find a word character (letter or number) or `]` followed by one of the listed operators, followed by a word character or quote.

This then replaces the match with the character found before the operator, a space, the matching operator, a space, and the character found after the operator.

You might end up adding other operators such as `+=`, `-=`, etc. You may need to add additional characters to match before or after the operator but this gives you a good start.

Comment: See the 3 sets of `( )` in the search string? Those are capture groups. In a replacement string, the $1 means the first capture group, $2, the second, etc.

Answer (score 1):

With your regular expression, you're matching all characters, whether or not they are a space.

Instead, try `[^\s<>=!]=[^\s=]`.

Explanation:

- The square brackets tell regex to match one example of something
  specified inside of them.
- The `^` at the beginning of the square brackets tells regex to look
  for something that isn't coming up.
- The `\s` matches something that is whitespace (as opposed to `\S`, which matches something that isn't).

Altogether, this says "Find a string that starts with something that isn't a space or a less than, greater than, not sign, or equals sign, followed by an equals sign, followed by another something that isn't a space or an equals sign."

Another possibility is `[a-zA-Z0-9]=[^\s=]`. This will find a letter or number next to an equals sign, followed by an equals sign followed by not an equals sign or a space.

Comment: `[^\s=]=[^\s=]` will match `<=`, `>=`, `!=` so it's still not good enough

Comment: @rmaddy Your suggestions work well. I need to find all cases like `var a=b`, `view.isHidden=false`, `if(a==b)`, etc. After using your suggestions I found the strings, but I have to give space manually. I'm unable to use replace all option

Answer (score 0):

You can find the same by using Insert Pattern option from Navigator:

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: This doesn't even match the example in the question.

Comment: @rmaddy Can you please check with provided format <Word>=<Word>, I have already checked and its working same as the example provided in question.

Comment: I did test it. <Word> won't match on the `"`.

Comment: for that you can use <Word>=" Pattern